# vmWare and maintenance mode on primary HA (DRS) host

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have to make a change to all my esxi hosts in a cluster that has DRS enabled, one of the hosts is the primary host for HA. As far as I know a host is selected by the system during an election process, what will happen if i put the primary host in maintenance mode, will this break DRS or will it just force a new election process. I have searched online and cannot find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a host in maintenance mode will not break DRS. An election process will be triggered when the host goes offline, this will not impact the DRS in any way.

Comment: Thank you Gerald, i will be doing this, this afternoon, but thank you for the reply, once I have completed this I will mark as correct :)